# Django, enabling html tag in the return value of admin.ModelAdmin class

Tags: python, django

For example, the code below.

I want to use `<pre>` tag in the django's admin.ModelAdmin

```
class MyJsonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['show_jsondata']
    def show_jsondata(self,obj):
        temp = json.dumps(obj.jsondata, indent=2)
        return "<pre>" +temp + "</pre>"
```

Is there any practice???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use format_html:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class MyJsonDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['show_jsondata']
    def show_jsondata(self,obj):
        temp = json.dumps(obj.jsondata, indent=2)
        return format_html("<pre>" +temp + "</pre>")
```

Comment: Thank you very much That's what I need.